# Update TFS 2013 update 2 license

Tags: tfs

TFS 2013 Update 2 install does not allow to input license key .License type is mentioned as MSDN and Update License link is not visible 
TFs 2013 installed on Windows server 2012 R2 Along with Sharepoint 2013.
How to apply license key to the TFS 2013?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to "apply" a license key with TFS.  When you download the TFS install media from MSDN the key is built into it (or not needed).

You are legally required to have an appropriate license to install and use TFS, but the software won't actively check that you're properly licensed.